# Usb device overcurrent

Tags: usb, motherboard

So i am a first time builder and i put everything together and the boots says usb device over current and the computer turns it self of in 15 seconds. I do everything the internet has to say on the issue i look for bent pins i do everything and it still does not work. I detached the front usb from the motherboard everything and it does not work please help me!
Im typing from a laptop. Im using a Asus h81m-1 motherboard. I first tried outside the case i tried i with no problem went to the bios. I installed the motherboard tested it and it did not work and i got my error.

Comment: What is connected via USB? Does the problem occur with no USB devices connected?

Comment: Yes it does occur when nothing is connected.

Comment: I have nothing except the video cable and the psu connected.

Comment: Have you disconnected all internal cables from the motherboard that connect to USB connectors on the case? (If you still have the problem, this would suggest a defective motherboard.)

Comment: Ok however the motherboard has worked before i put it in the case.

Comment: If all USB cables are disconnected from the MB and now it doesn't work, check for any sources of shorting (screws fastening the MB to the case, unsecured wire, etc.).  If it does work when you disconnect all of the cables, it points to damage/defect in cables or connectors, or possibly something shorting contacts on the USB connectors.

Comment: Im right now testing outside the case but there are some screws on motherboard i'll try.

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Get a USB volt meter, they are very cheap and show current too, and do some tests.

Comment: One last thing you can check.  There are lots of little cables with connectors that fit over a couple of pins on rows of pins on the MB.  Verify that everything is going to the right pins.  BTW, there is a certain percentage of "infant mortality" -- failures almost as soon as you start using it.  Inspect the MB carefully for any signs that you damaged it.  If you don't see any, it could just be a premature failure and you provided the QC check.  Assuming it's covered by a warranty, I would ask for a replacement.

Comment: Ok we went to the retailer and they provide pre professional help with tech stuff however thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if nothing already mentioned works, the motherboard is probably defective. This can also happen with new hardware! You should contact your dealer to get a replacement.

Comment: Ok but it worked before.

Comment: Does that meen i broke it?

Comment: What do you mean “it worked before”? I don’t see any mention of this in the question. Please explain, thoroughly.

Comment: Well i first tried outside the case i tried i with no problem went to the bios. I installed the motherboard tested it and it did not work and i got my error.

Comment: You should update your question to include this important detail. And yes, that means you probably broke it. Maybe you slipped with the screwdriver or whatever.

Comment: Wich means i need to pay for another one.

Comment: Is it repairable?

Comment: No way. Even an expert with intimate knowledge on this very motherboard model would struggle to find the exact cause.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that USB connector might have mangled. This most probably occurs from the front USB. Try detaching the front USB lead from the motherboard and see if your computer boots up.

Comment: I have done that.

Comment: Still the same??

Comment: Yes the same :(

Answer (score 0):

May be one of your ports is short circuited or something.

Disconnect all USB devices, memory cards and hubs except the keyboard and mouse.  Plug the keyboard and mouse into the back USB ports and give it a go.If you get the same issue then move the mouse to a front port. If the above doesn't work then use a flashlight can look closely into each back and front USB port for a bent pin.

Another thing to try is to open up the PC, find the USB cables going to a motherboard and header, remove one cable (marking where it was removed from) and then boot up and see if the issue persists.  Do the same procedure for each USB cable going to the motherboard. Then you can find out which port has problem. Then analyze that port further to see whether there is any problem with ports or pins.

Comment: I got a new board :P Thank you for making an answer.